# how to do max-match search in JCS (java caching system)

Tags: jcs

I am developing an application which makes use of JCS. i do know how to retrive the data from the catch when searchkey is a complete string. I need to implement max-match search in JCS.

For example : cache contains following data.

- book number | book title
- 123         | EJB
- 321         | Head First Java
- 121         | Jsp and servlets
- 111         | Ant scripting

when user inputs just 1 for book number it should fetch all the book title with book number starting with 1. i.e it should list

- EJB
- Jsp and servlets
- Ant scripting

It is the kind of search we do in sql using 'like and %' .

Kindly help me.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to to do something like this:

```
JCSAdminBean admin = new JCSAdminBean();
LinkedList<CacheElementInfo> cacheElements = admin.buildElementInfo("myCache");
for (CacheElementInfo e : cacheElements) {
    if (e.getKey().startsWith("1")) {
        //do something.. store it in a list?
    }
}
```

Try it out and let me know if that works for you.